# How to install many python extensions in one step

Tags: python

Is it possible to collect many Python extensions an install them in one step?  I have a Python build environment for an open source project that often needs to be recreated on multiple machine.  It's a pain to double click through a bunch of python extension exes every time we need to do this.

Ideally I'd like to package a complete build environment, Python, extensions, system environment variables, and all, into a one step install process.  But a single step extension install would also be helpful.  Is this possible?

Comment: When you say 'install' what do you actually mean? A PyInstaller type executable, .egg, pip??

Comment: When you say "extensions", do you mean specifically a "Python extension module", which is a module written in C? Or are you using "extensions" as another word for "library", which could be pure Python, a C extension module, or a mix of the two?

Comment: Also, do you wish to have all of this installed in an application-dependent manner (only one program, or each program with an automated installer, will have access to those extensions), or do you mean to install the extensions in a way that any python program run on the system will be able to use them?

Comment: Since your question is vague, I won't provide an answer, but I'd suggest that you take a look at [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (scroll down to Making Environments Relocatable, or possibly the Bootstrap section above), [`zc.buildout`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.0.0a5), and [`cx_Freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net), as well as @DivakarDass's suggestion of `pip`, to see if any of them are what you want.

Comment: @PenguinCoder The build enviornment is in windows so I'm often doing a windows install of the packages from this page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/.  As a simple example, I download numpy-unoptimized-1.6.2.win32-py2.7.‌exe, double click on it to install, then it exists in the Python 2.7 environment on that machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do that... do you have `pip(python indexed package)` installed in your system?
if not, then install it... and put all the extensions into a single text file... say requirements.txt...

This is done by running

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

then by using pip you can install it... by using this command...

`pip install -r requirements.txt`...

it will install all the extensions mentioned in the file...

you can find the pip package here [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)
might help you...

Comment: +1. You may also want to look at the package-index features, so you can include the actual packages as well as the frozen requirements file. See [here](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#alternate-package-repositories) and below for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can with [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) define dependencies of a package, and easy_install or [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) will install all dependencies when you ask to install the package.

Comment: So an empty package where setup.py only has dependencies?

Comment: @Rich that could be an option, sure. I do that for my customer setups all the time. :-) But that's webservers, so it's a bit special.